# Python rasterio error, unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

My question is about setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to the right directory. I have read some posts where they had the same issue as me and the advice was to set the GDAL_DATA environment, but I'm at a loss of how to do that.

I am using rasterio (& rioxarray) to reproject a raster to another CRS. This worked until I tried to install some other stuff on linux and now I get the following error when I try to run it:

> ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the
> GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing
> EPSG csv files.

The script still runs, but when it gets to the reprojection:

```
worldpop = worldpop.rio.reproject(dst_crs=region_gdf.crs, resolution=500, resampling=Resampling.bilinear)
```

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "rasterio/_base.pyx", line
> 1455, in rasterio._base._osr_from_crs   File "rasterio/_err.pyx", line
> 192, in rasterio._err.exc_wrap_int rasterio._err.CPLE_AppDefinedError:
> PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/jochem/Uppermoor/coronalocatie-datapipeline/uk/create_grid.py",
> line 47, in 
> worldpop = worldpop.rio.reproject(dst_crs=region_gdf.crs, resolution=500, resampling=Resampling.bilinear)   File
> "/home/jochem/.local/share/virtualenvs/coronalocatie-datapipeline-8r7cFbTs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rioxarray/raster_array.py",
> line 371, in reproject
> rasterio.warp.reproject(   File "/home/jochem/.local/share/virtualenvs/coronalocatie-datapipeline-8r7cFbTs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasterio/env.py",
> line 387, in wrapper
> return f(*args, **kwds)   File "/home/jochem/.local/share/virtualenvs/coronalocatie-datapipeline-8r7cFbTs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasterio/env.py",
> line 610, in wrapper
> return f(*args, **kwds)   File "/home/jochem/.local/share/virtualenvs/coronalocatie-datapipeline-8r7cFbTs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasterio/warp.py",
> line 363, in reproject
> _reproject(   File "rasterio/_warp.pyx", line 399, in rasterio._warp._reproject   File "rasterio/_warp.pyx", line 373, in
> rasterio._warp._reproject   File "rasterio/_io.pyx", line 1765, in
> rasterio._io.InMemoryRaster.**init**   File "rasterio/_base.pyx", line
> 1461, in rasterio._base._osr_from_crs rasterio.errors.CRSError: PROJ:
> proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db

Some background information: I run this in a pip environment where rasterio is installed. The packages are installed in .local/share/virtualenvs/.../lib/python3.9/site-packages.
I can find rasterio here, but the folder: rasterio/gdal_data does not contain a gcs.csv file.

Also, do I need to install GDAL seperately to make this work or is installing rasterio enough, because I struggle with getting GDAL installed as well.